# ssl tls 1.2 error ACCEPT_SR_KEY_EXCH ssl handshake failure

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, wireshark, tls1.3

There is a client and a server which are using the SSL/TLS protocol v1.2 to communicate. The server has a valid certificate issued by the zerossl trusted authority. The client is verified that it can establish connection to other SSL/TLS protected resources successfully. The server also verified that it can establish SSL/TLS connection with other clients. There is a problem when pairing together particular client with the server. The error message says:

OpenSSL Error[0]: error:140370E5:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_KEY_EXCH:ssl handshake failure

when I try to debug the SSL/TLS using the Wireshark, I see that there is a Client Hello, afte that the Server Hello, then Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done and it repeats in a sequence again:

Client Hello, after that the Server Hello, then Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done

Client Hello, after that the Server Hello, then Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done

Client Hello, after that the Server Hello, then Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done

the most weird thing is that both the client and the server can successfully pair with other parties: servers and clients.

in the Wireshark logs I see that the protocol **sometimes says TLSv1.2 and sometimes it says TLSv1.3**

please, take into account that the client connects successfully to other SSL/TLS servers and same for the server - it connects successfully with other clients via SSL/TLS.

[image]

Comment: OpenSSL doesn't use that function code nor that style of function name; are you sure this program isn't actually using one of the forks, LibreSSL or BoringSSL, which people including developers and thus programs often still label as OpenSSL? The message sequence you highlight is correct for _part_ of some TLS1.2 (or lower) handshakes, and the error suggests the client code thinks there's a problem with the ServerKeyExchange, so you might look at that, and compare to what it should be given the ServerHello, Certificate, and any sigalgs and maybe eccurves in the ClientHello.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for explaining. What function is not used by the OpenSSL? Can you please point me exactly to it? Like I've said, the server works fine with multiple other clients. It fails with just ONE particular client, how that could be possible? I'm not SSL TLS expert, that's why this behavior is very weird from my point of view.

Comment: In OpenSSL below 3.0.0 error code 140370E5 breaks down as 'library' 0x14=20=libssl, 'function' 0x037=55, 'reason' 0x0E5=229. Real OpenSSL assigns function numbers to functions, which have lowercase names, and there is no function #55. I can't point to an exact location of something that doesn't exist, but in https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/include/openssl/sslerr.h you can see there is no SSL_F_ definition with value 55.

Comment: LibreSSL for libssl instead assigns function numbers to _states_ which have uppercase names, and #55 (or #56) [is indeed ACCEPT_SR_KEYKEY_EXCH](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/lib/libssl/ssl_err.c?rev=1.46&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup). I don't know which or what Boring does. There are two possibilties: (1) server is indeed sending something bad in ServerKeyExchange to this client, but other clients don't see the problem because they don't use DHE (at all), don't use the same type of DHE (FF vs EC), or don't use the same curve/group for DHE, or get a different signature type ...

Comment: ... (2) server is sending valid ServerKeyExchange that triggers a bug in client, but other servers don't because they don't use DHE, don't use the same DHE, or the same curve/group, or the same signature. Without actually looking at the details, I don't think there's any way you can diagnose or solve this problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 could it be a certificate issue? It is worth to try another certificate from a different authority? what other details are needed to point exactly where the bug comes from and to understand how to resolve this?

Comment: In the KEYEXCH state the client has already received and validated the cert, so it's not the CA. It _could_ be the signature, as I mentioned, so using a cert with a different key _type_ (aka algorithm, e.g. EC(DSA) instead of RSA or vice versa) _might_ help.